# Oracle AFTER INSERT trigger not firing

Tags: oracle, select, triggers, insert

I have been tasked with having to create a trigger after an insert. Here are the tables involved:

```
CREATE TABLE purchase(
orderid CHAR(3),
unit_price NUMBER(7,2),
sales_price NUMBER(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
itemid CHAR(3)
);
```

And here is the trigger:

```
/* Now we need the AFTER trigger */
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DoubleSalesPrice
AFTER INSERT on purchase
FOR EACH ROW


DECLARE
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
itemcount smallint;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(itemid) INTO itemcount FROM purchase P WHERE P.itemid = :new.itemid;
IF (itemcount = 1) THEN
    UPDATE purchase P 
    SET P.sales_price = 2*P.unit_price
    WHERE P.orderid = :new.orderid;
end if;
end;
/
```

I have specified this as an AFTER INSERT per the code. However, when I insert into Purchase, I do not get the desired result:

```
INSERT INTO purchase VALUES( '100','250', '200', '500');
SQL> select * from purchase;

ORD UNIT_PRICE SALES_PRICE ITE
--- ---------- ----------- ---
100        250         200 500
```

It doesn't appear as if the trigger is firing. I have made sure to enable it with the same results:

```
ALTER TRIGGER DoubleSalesPrice enable;
SQL> select * from purchase;

ORD UNIT_PRICE SALES_PRICE ITE
--- ---------- ----------- ---
101        250         200 500
```

If anyone has any suggestions please let me know. I usually like to build small examples before I attempt the actual problem. This one mirrors the functionality I need to attain.

Comment: Is it an issue with commit?  Just wondering.

Comment: I get no errors. I Did try a commit and then the entire trigger just bombed. Logged out of SQLPlus, ran it again, no issue. The trigger is just not firing.

Comment: I didn't get what 'bombed' exactly did to SQL*Plus.

Comment: http://pastie.org/7354543

This is the error I receive now. Cannot even do an insert after logging out and logging back in.

Comment: Sorry for a late reply, but I am in a different time zone  :)

This is related to the PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION statement.  Are you sure you need that statement?  You need to commit or rollback an autonomous transaction.  Best way is to remove it because the INSERT and the TRIGGER should be executed in the same transaction.
Correct me if wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is an `autonomous transaction`, you have to commit it within its local scope, that is to say the trigger itself.

I don't think you should do it though, it doesn't make sense to make it separate (the transaction) from the insert itself. It should be commited with the whole process.

Comment: Is there any alternative to doing what I need with a trigger? The requirements state it needs to be a trigger so I am getting a bit worried.

Comment: yes, just remove the PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION from your code

Comment: I placed the PRAGMA_AUTONOMOUS_TRANSCATION line to get rid of the first issue. I am getting a mutating table error now.

Comment: Unfortunately my assignment states that I must use an AFTER INSERT trigger.

Comment: what if you remove the select? Do you still have the mutation error?

Comment: I think removing the select will make the error not appear. However, I am not certain how to determine how many time the itemid appears in the table. Eventually there will be more logic to this. If the item appears once, I want to set sales_price to double the unit_price. If the item appears more than once, it will be an average.

Comment: this article of asktom.com tells you more about your possible solution: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551198119097816936

Comment: I've already seen that. I'm not able to implement that type of solution. Can you provide an example with a package? I do not understand the output.